# Hiding column in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a little grid:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 firefox">
        <h2>Firefox fix</h2>
        <p>If firefox is prompting for password click button below.</p>
    </div>
```

And I want to hide the div with 3rd column.
I was trying to do this with css:

```
<style>
   div.firefox {
       display:none !important;
   }
</style>
```

with no effect.

I need to modify something more?

Comment: There seems to be more than meets the eye. Are you sure that there isn't any other styling on the div that displays it?

Comment: What does the inspector in dev tools say? Is your CSS declared *before* Bootstrap?

Comment: Its bootstrap so its highly possible that there is styling on the `col-md-4`

Comment: @MackieeE I think I found problem. VS refuses to add changes to my code and always run old code without new styling...

Answer (score 0):

You can use visibility class built in bootstrap

reference [helper-classes-show-hide](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-show-hide)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in Visual Studio caching old code. 
After deleting all visual studio cache problem disappeared just like that div ;)

Comment: That's why I always do a hard refresh (Ctrl + Shit + R) to be absolutely sure.

Comment: Read again my answer. It's not browser cache. Old code remains ins IDE (visual studio cache). Its needed to be deleted manually